# Offset smooth scroll bootstrap JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need the smooth scroll to be offset by 100px. So far I have this:

```js
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This gets my link moving! But how can I add .offset().top > 100 to this? I am having issues figuring it out if anyone can help out.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. Create a jsfiddle or jsbin please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a fixed navbar. Assuming your anchors are empty:

```
<a class="anchor" id="foo"></a>
```

Just offset the anchors in css:

```
.anchor {
    top: -100px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Alternatively you can offset the scrollTop by updating your javascript:

```
scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 100
```

Answer (score 1):

**ve1jdramas** Hi there.
Have a look at this **[link here](http://www.widecodes.com/CmVjeeUgUP/smooth-scrolling-scrollspy-and-bootstrap.html)**.

In this example, they use **+** or **-** .

Like this...
`scrollTop: target.offset().top -100`
or
`scrollTop: target.offset().top +100`

Try this and see if you can get this to work for you.
Or use this full code.

```
$(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top -100
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
```